# How Django bulks create check exist already in bulks objs and instance?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have a lot of data, that data is pretty dirty, example:

**A table ORM :**

```
id = models.CharField(default='', max_length=50)
time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
number = models.CharField(default='', max_length=20)
value = models.CharField(default='', max_length=20)

unique_together = ['id', 'time', 'number']
```

**A table DATA :**

```
id   time                   number   value
 1     2018-07-16 00:00:00   1         64
 1     2018-07-16 00:00:00   2         -99
 1     2018-07-16 00:00:00   3         655
 1     2018-07-16 00:00:00   4         3
 2     2018-07-16 00:00:00   0         12
```

**Import Datas (sample) :**

```
id   time                   number   value
 1     2018-07-16 00:00:00   1         64
 3     2018-07-16 00:00:00   0         -99
 3     2018-07-16 00:00:00   0         11
 4     2018-07-16 00:00:00   0         -99
 4     2018-07-16 00:00:00   1         -99
```

So, When I Do

```
for loop....
    objs = []
    objs.append(A(**kwargs))
A.objects.bulk_create(objs, batch_size=50000)
```

It will raise two kind duplicate.

1. A Table already exist   **" 1     2018-07-16 00:00:00   1"**
2. Import Datas already exist  **3     2018-07-16 00:00:00   0** for two times in objs, so when I bulks create it will raise duplicate, then it will roll back all commit !!!

the "1",  I can use get or create to solve it 
but "2", I can't check now I append data exist in the objs or not
I tried to use this to check exist or not, but when data row over 1000000, 
the complexity  will be terrible.

```
def search(id, time, number, objs):
    for obj in objs:
        if obj['id'] == id and obj['time'] == time and obj['number'] == number:
            return True
    return False
```

Is there have any better way? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a tuple with `id`, `time` and `number` to a `set`:

```
objs = []
duplicate_check = set()
for loop....
    data = kwargs['id'], kwargs['time'], kwargs['number']
    if not data in duplicate_check:
        objs.append(A(**kwargs))
        duplicate_check.add(data)
A.objects.bulk_create(objs, batch_size=50000)
```

The `set` operations have a complexity of O(1).

Comment: Sorry, my data set had another item, but I didn't show. I can't guarantee value also unique

Comment: That's no problem, the tuple `data` should only contain the columns covered by the unique constraint. Or do you want to store the last value in the database?

Comment: Oh !! I got it, thanks a lot, I will try the performance, thank you :D

Comment: But, When I have 1000000 rows data need to check data in duplicate_check, that will run O(1) => 1000000 times... then when I do 1000001 , that would be run 1000001 times... that's also terrible !!!

Comment: Well, if you want to work with n items, you will have to do n operations. The duplicate check is in memory, so it is probably still negligible compared to the database operations.